# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Audio-Video Production Stack Exchange](http://avp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [MP4 video rendering differently on different browsers and different machines](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8285/mp4-video-rendering-differently-on-different-browsers-and-different-machines)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Lossless screen-recording software](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8305/lossless-screen-recording-software)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8320/is-there-a-way-to-export-midi-tracks-from-rebirth

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8374/is-it-safe-to-connect-2-players-to-a-single-pair-of-headphones-using-y-splitter

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8292/play-in-scale-like-abletons-push-controller-using-a-drum-rack-other

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to change note value in Ableton Live](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/how-to-change-note-value-in-ableton-live)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [batch audio + picture slideshow video creation for youtube](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8453/batch-audio-picture-slideshow-video-creation-for-youtube)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/audio-interface-guitar-pedal-chain-audio-interface

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/how-to-correctly-slow-down-the-track-to-compensate-for-wrong-bitrate

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Would it be legal to use Cott-produced, generic beverages in a film?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/would-it-be-legal-to-use-cott-produced-generic-beverages-in-a-film)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)